# I think my local variable isn't being updated

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm writing a function that should return `True` if the parameter is a leap year and `False` if it isn't, but for some reason it returns `True` no matter what integer value gets passed. Since the local variable that it returns is initialised to `True`, I suspect the issue might be that it's not being updated even though the necessary conditions are met:

```
def is_leap(year):
    leap = True
    if year%4 == 1:
        leap = False
    elif year%100 == 0 and year%400 == 1:
        leap = False
    return leap


for ayear in [1944,2011,1986,1800,1900,2000,2056]:
    print(is_leap(ayear)) #this returns True for every item?????
```

Any help?

Comment: Which years do you expect it to return False for? Why? What year is the most recent leap year that has happened? What does your code give (True or False) for that year?

Comment: Glad you figured it out :)

Comment: @reggaelizard, I suggest putting that as your answer here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know to solve it in php, your conditions are wrong!!!

```
$arr = array(1944, 2011, 2012, 2013, 2014, 1986, 1800, 1900, 2000, 2056);

    function leapYear($year){
        if(($year % 4) == 0 && ($year % 100) != 0){
            return true;
        }
        else{
            return false;
        }
    }

    for($i = 0; $i < count($arr) ; $i++){
        $r = leapYear($arr[$i]);

        if($r){
            echo 'Lepo year: ' . $arr[$i] . '<br>';
        }else{
            echo 'Not Leap year: ' . $arr[$i] . '<br>';
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Oops, I think I figured it out – I was thinking in terms of odd and even and that only works for `n%2 == 0`. I just changed the conditions to

```
if year%4 != 0:
    leap = False
elif year%100 == 0 and year%400 != 0:
    leap = False
```

and it's working fine now.